# is it a security hole to verify an uploaded supposed-to-be-zip file as a zip with zip_open()?

Tags: files, security

Question's subject is pretty much it.

I have an upload widget on a custom content type that is for users to provide a zip file.

I want to verify the file they provide is indeed a zip file, and take appropriate action if not. However, first I need to know if it's safe to pass an unknown file type to zip_open(), probably using the ZIP_CHECKONS flag for extra integrity checks.

edit: just realized ZIP_CHECKONS is not exposed in php. :(

Is this a safe way to verify a file is a zip file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems reasonable to me. I would probably place the file in a temporary directory first and then use zip_open on it in that location.

You may also be able to use OS level commands (which come with their own risks) to verify the integrity of the file without actually unzipping it.

Are you going to store the zip files as zip files after being uploaded? Doing so presents additional issues since zips can be used to contain lots of files that may or may not be appropriate. You may want to get a list of the contents of the file to automatically include in your field so people downloading them will know if the file contents are valid. You could also integrate with something like http://drupal.org/project/clamav to scan all the files that are uploaded.

Comment: Greggles, thanks for the very informative answer. The zip files are intended to be user contributed digital download products at an online store. So there is moderation, as in each zip file is opened, examined & tested by human staff before being added to the online store. Something like clamAV looks quite important to integrate into the workflow, for some measure of internal protection. Thanks again!